# Accents displayed correctly half the time

Tags: php, encoding, non-ascii-characters

My issue is as simple as it sounds, but can't find why it happens. I don't understand everything with encoding but here, on the same page, when I hit F5 to reload it, the accent only show up half the time. Which is very strange..

The string comes from a database where a table stores it as a VARCHAR encoded in latin1_swedish_ci. The accents in the database are correctly displayed.

I think nothing is wrong with that as with an other table and the same encoding, the accents don't have any problem.

Any idea on where it could mess up?

Comment: Please provide samples. What characters error, when, etc. The are displaying as the black diamond with question mark?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) (Check that you have covered _all_ the aspects mentioned in there.)

Comment: @user3783243 Problem is that there is no particular pattern, I tested and the problem occurred with every accents, and yes this display a black diamond. As on my other page there is no problem (exactly same head included to all my pages)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! This post took my deeper into utf8 and utf8mb4 encodings, I reviewed my php settings, mysql settings, and database strings' charset, and now it works.

Comment: @CBroe Nah, correction, it doesn't work for me. Still my accents half the time. Won't loose my time here, I don't have the knowledges for that, will resolve this problem later!